# Hibernate Error Message

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, sql-server-2005, spring

I have scoured the web in search of a solution to this problem, but with little to no luck. I am using Hibernate with MS SQL Server, Flex and Java on Eclipse Helios. When I try to run the mxml file on my Tomcat server, I get the following (abbreviated) error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingDestinationExporter#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is flex.messaging.config.ConfigurationException:Cannot add destination with id 'myDestination' to service with id 'remoting-service' because another service with id 'remoting-service' already has a destination with the same id.
```

Here is the corresponding stack trace:

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? I'd be more than happy to provide any additional info. Thanks.

Comment: What gives you this error?  Is it a runtime exception from the Flash Player?  Or something else?  This doesn't look like a Flex based stack trace.

Comment: I don't believe it is a Flex error, but a Hibernate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have multiple xml (configuration) files and one of them has the id as `remoting-service`.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingDestinationExporter#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is flex.messaging.config.ConfigurationException:Cannot add destination with id 'myDestination' to service with id 'remoting-service' because
**another service with id 'remoting-service' already has a destination with the same id.**

you need to check all your spring config files to find & rename on of the id's.

Comment: That's what I figured as well, but from the looks of it, I have the following configuration files: messaging-config, proxy-config, remoting-config, services-config, flex-config and hibernate-config. Each of these appears to have a unique ID name.

Comment: look for a config of a destination  called `myDestination`... that's where the problem is.

Comment: That would be remoting-config, which indeed has the id:'remoting-service'. However, there are no other config files I can see that share that same ID.

Comment: Cannot add destination with id 'myDestination' to service with id 'remoting-service' because another service with id 'remoting-service' already has a destination with the same id..

check to see if you have a config which has a property (for destination) with a reference to myDestination.

Comment: I do have a config file with that property. It is called remoting-config. Thanks to your advice, I was able to locate a solution to the problem. I modified the xls file that produces the remoting config xlm so that it gives it a different id. This seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks again.